# Tracker-extract and Tracker-store processes consuming huge Amount of RAM

Tags: linux, arch-linux, file-search, indexing

I am using Arch Linux, kernel 3.16.

From last one week my two processes tracker-extract and tracker-store are taking too much RAM. It results in hangup of system once in every 2 hours.

**tracker-extract taking 300 MB and tracker -store taking 2 GB RAM.**

I want to know what are these tracker processes and what are their work. If i kill them does this effect in system performance ?

What are the ways to kill them permanently so that I can get rid of these two processes?

Please help me.